# embed tinymce in your asp.net mvc website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce

is there any example code of setting up tinymce within your web application using asp.net mvc?

Comment: actually this seems to be a better site: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=4680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you asking?

Your view is HTML. Any example of setting up TinyMCE on a typical HTML page would work on MVC. The only difference might be if you use *<%= Html.TextBox(...)*, in which case you use use the ID that you pass into the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I have written some partial view templates for TinyMCE. (I also push TinyMCE to the feed when it is being updated)

Following article will walk you through for the process :

**TinyMCE HTML Text Editior & ASP.NET MVC - Setting It Up Has Become Easy With Nuget**

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget